# How to read combobox from a thread other than the thread it was created on?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, invoke

I am trying to read a combobox.Text from a thread other than the thread it was created on but I am getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread
>   operation not valid: Control
>   'levelsComboBox' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

I have used .Invoke before but only to set properties, how can I use it to read combobox.Text? Because .Invoke returns void and I need a string. Or is there another way to do it without the Invoke?

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of the [How to get return value when BeginInvoke/Invoke is called in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214002/how-to-get-return-value-when-begininvoke-invoke-is-called-in-c)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        text = combobox.Text;
    });
```

Comment: i've 2 days searching for this solution. thnx

Comment: Works great. It helped me implement the Observer pattern in C#.

Answer (score 18):

You can still use `Invoke` and read it to a local variable.

Something like this:

```
string text;

this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { text = combobox.Text; }));
```

Since `Invoke` is synchronous you have the guarantee that `text` variable will contain the value of the combo box text after it returns.

Answer (score 5):

Shortest way is:

```
string text;
this.Invoke(() => text = combobox.Text);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work.  See link:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/395813/system-delegate-is-not-a-delegate-type

Comment: @YongkeBillYu the link asks to sign in. I don't see why wouldn't it work though, it should do the same as the accepted solution.

Comment: @Igor there's a caveat though: compiler complains on the code unless [you're cast it into Action type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411579/why-must-a-lambda-expression-be-cast-when-supplied-as-a-plain-delegate-parameter). Please, edit the code.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class to execute work on another thread, while still being able to update the UI (e.g. when reporting progress or when the task has completed).