# The program has unexpectedly finished in QDateTime::currentdatetime

Tags: c++, qt

I am running a thread, but sometimes the program dies. I hope you could tell me why that exit. Error

> glibc detected /home/hsr/CMBU-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/CMBU: corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000026192e0

Backtrace:

> 00400000-00437000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2499001                         /home/hsr/CMBU-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/CMBU
>   00636000-00637000 r--p 00036000 08:01 2499001                            /home/hsr/CMBU-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/CMBU
>   00637000-00638000 rw-p 00037000 08:01 2499001                            /home/hsr/CMBU-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_in_PATH__System__Release/CMBU
>   02410000-02c5f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
>   7fe2ff74d000-7fe2ffb72000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2755027                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/nanum/NanumGothic.ttf
>   7fe2ffb72000-7fe300000000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 6717449                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
>   7fe300000000-7fe300022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe300022000-7fe304000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe304000000-7fe304132000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe304132000-7fe308000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe308000000-7fe308022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe308022000-7fe30c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe30c26c000-7fe30c2cc000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 6750219                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
>   7fe30c2cc000-7fe30c6e4000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2755028                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/nanum/NanumGothicBold.ttf
>   7fe30c6e4000-7fe30c6e5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>   7fe30c6e5000-7fe30cee5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

```
void Thread::run()
{
    while (!stopped) {
        if(messageStr==tr("A")) {
            MainCMBU::ui->dateTimeEdit->setDateTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime());
            msleep(1000);
        }
    }
    //std::cerr << qPrintable(messageStr);
    stopped = false;
}
```

Comment: You canot access UI component from another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450750/can-you-access-ui-elements-from-another-thread-get-not-set

Comment: @Ashif Threading may be the issue, but the linked question is a completely different language and platform.

Comment: Try to use QMetaObject::invokeMethod(MainCMBU::ui->dateTimeEdit, "setDateTime", Q_ARG(QDateTime, QDateTime::currentDateTime());

Comment: @Yaroslav thank , Is there a difference? what mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a QTimer to update your UI in UI thread
2. Use that same QTimer to do work, if you plan on doing work
3. If there is too much work for GUI, use QtConcurrent::run() or similar to do non-GUI work. Use a QFutureWatcher if you need to know when that asynchronous operation is complete.

Sleeping in a thread like you are doing is generally bad design.

In Qt, you cannot access GUI thread elements from non-GUI thread. GUI is NOT threadsafe.

Comment: How do you change it?

Comment: Like I told you. You'll need a design overhaul to fix your code. Both, what you posted and what you didn't post.